# Push values on to a key in an associative array

Tags: php, arrays

Given:

```
$groups           = EveMarketGroupsEntity::distinct()->select('name')->get();
$groupInformation = [];

if (!is_null($groups)) {
    foreach ($groups as $group) {
    }
}
```

How do I do the following *properly*

```
if (!is_null($groups)) {
    foreach ($groups as $group) {
        $groupInformation[$group->name][]= EveMarketGroupsEntity::where('name', $group->name)->first()->item();
    }
}
```

Right now I get:

```
array:818 [▼
  "Weaponry" => array:1 [▶]
  ...
]
```

When `Weaponry` should have more then 1 element. In fact:

```
array:818 [▼
  "Weaponry" => array:1 [▶]
  "Special Edition Industrial Ships" => array:1 [▶]
  "Nanite Injectors" => array:1 [▶]
  "Vehicles and Gear" => array:1 [▶]
  "Rapid Light Missile Launchers" => array:1 [▶]
  "Standard Light Missiles" => array:1 [▶]
  "Jump Bridge" => array:1 [▶]
  "Missile Launcher Rigs" => array:1 [▶]
  "Strip Miners" => array:1 [▶]
  "Freighters" => array:1 [▶]
  ...
]
```

They should all have more then 1 element. **What am I missing?**

**Question:** How do I push the same element on to the same key thus creating an array: `array('key' => [elm, elm, elm ...])`

Comment: i think `first()->item();`  will return only first row?

Comment: Are you sure $groups  is an array of arrays after calling EveMarketGroupsEntity::distinct()->select('name')->get(); ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me ...

```
foreach ($groups as $group) {
    $groupInformation[$group->name] = EveMarketGroupsEntity::where('name', $group->name)->first()->item()->get()->all();
}
```

[Larvel Collection - `all()` docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-all)